# How to get the start time and end time from calendar events in android?

Tags: android, events, android-calendar

I want to get the start time and end time of the calendar event in android?How can i achive it?

This is my code,

```
public static void readCalendarEvent(Context context) throws ParseException {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dtstart = "dtstart";
        String dtend = "dtend";


        SimpleDateFormat    displayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("  MMMM dd, yyyy (EEEE)");

         stime=displayFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());     

        SimpleDateFormat startFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        String dateString = startFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());

        long after = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat formatterr = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");
        Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dateCCC = formatterr.parse("47:59:59 " + dateString);
        endOfDay.setTime(dateCCC);



        cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), (new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }), "(" + dtstart + ">" + after + " and " + dtend + "<" + endOfDay.getTimeInMillis() + ")", null, "dtstart ASC");
        gCalendar = new ArrayList<GoogleCalendar>();
        try {
            System.out.println("Count=" + cursor.getCount());

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                System.out.println("the control is just inside of the cursor.count loop");
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    GoogleCalendar googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendar();
                    gCalendar.add(googleCalendar);
                    int calendar_id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    googleCalendar.setCalendar_id(calendar_id);
                    String title = cursor.getString(1);
                    googleCalendar.setTitle(title);
                    String description = cursor.getString(2);
                    googleCalendar.setDescription(description);
                    String dtstart1 = cursor.getString(3);
                    googleCalendar.setDtstart(dtstart1);                    
                    System.out.println("Starting date is :" +dtstart1);
                    String dtend1 = cursor.getString(4);
                    googleCalendar.setDtend(dtend1);
                    String eventlocation = cursor.getString(5);
                    googleCalendar.setEventlocation(eventlocation);
                }
            }
        } catch (AssertionError ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine but, I want to get the start time end time from this code.I can i achieve it?

Comment: I am getting the end date like this( end date is: -1881036608)

Comment: what do you mean start and end time? You have string representations of them.

Answer (score 0):

Android's Calendar event gives start or end date in milliseconds from the epoch of time (Jan 1, 1970). So I copied a code fragment from someone to convert milliseconds to date and time. the function is

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
            return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());


}
```

Then I call it like this to get date time value where i'm implementing

```
Log.d("start date", getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A handy website if you want to convert time http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/

Answer (score 0):

```
String currentDateTimeString = java.text.SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
StartDate.setText(currentDateTimeString);
String current = java.text.SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
EndDate.setText(current);
```

Comment: Add explanations please!